# can I reuse an form that has been disposed for multiple forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I have written a below code to reuse the disposed form. But this is hard coded, limited to only one form. I would like to use the same to check and open the all form in my application.

```
    private void CheckMdiChildren(Form frm)
    {
        if (frm.IsDisposed)
        {
            frm = new MembersList();
            frm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                if (f.GetType() == frm.GetType())
                {
                    f.Focus();
                    return;
                }
            }
            frm.MdiParent = this;
            frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
```

I am passing the parameter frm which is object for different forms, for ex.

```
        this.CheckMdiChildren(mbl);
```

and

```
        this.CheckMdiChildren(exc);
```

but above code always opens the MembersList form.

I have declared below forms globally for MainForm

```
    ExerciseChart exc = new ExerciseChart();
    MembersList mbl = new MembersList();
```

When I use above declaration locally it works fine.

Is there any way which I can use this function for multiple forms??

Quick help appreciated, don't hesitate to ask for more details or code!

Comment: Try changing your CheckMdiChildren() method to use "ref" on the parameter, and on all calls to the method.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not clear enough. The code you've provided seem to imply that your `this` form is the container and you are trying to "check" the children forms. Is it the case that only one of each type of children form is allowed? What is the context of the call site? How are the `mbl` and `exc` variable declared? Do you also want to update their values as part of this operation? Too many details have been left out to know what a good answer would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110%29.aspx) is able to create instances in runtime. Use your form parameter as type for the activator and cast the `CreateInstance` method to `Form`

```
var form = ( Form ) Activator.CreateInstance( frm.GetType() );
```